# Обучение нейронных сетей с помощью алгоритма обратного распространения ошибки

Tags: c++, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Здравствуйте. Пытался реализовать вот этот алгоритм http://robocraft.ru/blog/algorithm/560.html однако когда провел обучение сети, обнаружил, что выходные данные даже близко не соответствуют действительности. Где же я допустил ошибку? Или алгоритм по ссылке неправильный? Помогите разобраться.

```
double OpenNNL::_changeWeightsByBP(double * trainingInputs, double *trainingOutputs, double speed, double sample_weight)
{
    double * localGradients = new double[_neuronsCount];
    double * outputs = new double[_neuronsCount];
    double * derivatives = new double[_neuronsCount];

    calculateNeuronsOutputsAndDerivatives(trainingInputs, outputs, derivatives);

    for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[_layersCount-1];j++)
    {
        localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(_layersCount-1, j)] = trainingOutputs[j] - outputs[indexByLayerAndNeuron(_layersCount-1, j)];
    }

    if(_layersCount > 1)
    {
        for(int i=_layersCount-2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i];j++)
            {
                localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] = 0;

                for(int k=0;k<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i+1];k++)
                {
                    localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] += _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(i+1, k, j)]
                                                                    * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i+1, k)];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[0];j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<_inputsCount;k++)
        {
            _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(0, j, k)] += speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)]
                    * derivatives[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)] * trainingInputs[k];
        }
    }

    for(int i=1;i<_layersCount;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i];j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i-1];k++)
            {
                _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(i, j, k)] += speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)]
                        * derivatives[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] * outputs[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)];
            }
        }
    }

    delete[] localGradients;
    delete[] outputs;
    delete[] derivatives;
}
```

И в том алгоритме не сказано, как настраивать смещения нейронов. Может кто-нибудь подсказать как это делать?

Если вам понадобится полный код, то он здесь: https://github.com/NicholasShatokhin/OpenNNL

Comment: в метках укажите ЯП, который использовали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ох, нашел ошибку. В последнем цикле нужно было вместо outputs[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)]; написать: outputs[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i-1, k)];

Все беды от невнимательности.

Answer (score 0):

Таблица весовых коэффициентов синапсов localGradients должна быть размера _neuronsCount*_neuronsCount.

Answer (score 0):

Я вот изучил данный алгоритм по ресурсу, который вы предоставили. Так вот, вы, наверное, "не заметили", что вторая часть полностью посвящена выявлению ошибки в выходном сигнале Y **методом обратного распространения ошибки**.

```
Выходной сигнал сети y сравнивается с желаемым выходным сигналом z, который хранится в тренировочных данных. 
Разница между этими двумя сигналами называется ошибкой d выходного слоя сети.
```

Ну, а далее, после этого уже идет выявление нейрона( или связки нейронов одного уровня ), где произошла ошибка( `по контрольной сумме, вычисленной функцией f(x) или по суммам контрольных сумм, если имеем дело со связкой` ). Выявление происходит распространении сигнала ошибки d (вычисленного в шаге обучения) обратно на все нейроны, чьи выходные сигналы были входящими для последнего нейрона. Собственно, поэтому алгоритм так и называется.

Comment: И чего именно я не заметил?